# where and why do we use ReactDOMServer.renderToString()? And do we use this method in today's version of react?

Tags: reactjs

So I got to know about this method recently but I'am unable to understand that where do I use this method and is it necessary to use this method?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use it if you don't mind about Server-Side Rendering(SSR).

There are 2 types of rendering Client-Side Rendering and SSR.

You can tell that a site uses SSR when you request a page using postman say for example `http://youtube.com`, the server returns the html markup together with dynamic data from the backend. It is very crucial for SEO purposes to allow bots to crawl your app. It also improves performance of your site by First Contentful Paint(FCP) and Time to Interactive (TTI) metrics.

`rendertoString` method is used in the server side to convert a react component instance into a HTML string.

On the other side, CSR just returns this markup from the server.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- More tags here -->
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Most of the react-apps like create-react-app are client-side rendered. The markup with dynamic data is rendered by the browser.